# Js file inside node_modules is not accessible to index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, stencils

I am playing with [stencil](https://stenciljs.com/docs/getting-started/) 
What I have done so far:

1. Created a component in stencil
2. Published it to the npm
3. Created a angular project
4. Installed stencil component to the angular project
5. Added component.js file to the index.html file

When I am adding

```
<script src="/node_modules/stencil-poc-ng/dist/mycomponent.js"></script>
```

then brower console giving the following error:

GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/stencil-poc-ng/dist/mycomponent.js 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:4200/node_modules/stencil-poc-ng/dist/mycomponent.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building an Angular app, it won't be able to access a local path on your computer when running on your browser.
What Angular `ng serve`does:

- Bundle all of your code and dependencies in a HTML file, a CSS file and a bunch of JS files
- Save all of these files in memory (RAM)
- Launch a web server to serve these files

Only the "in memory" files are served, then your `http://localhost:4200/node_modules/stencil-poc-ng/dist/mycomponent.js` will always be invalid

You have only two options left:

- Import your JS file so that it is included in Angular build
- Use `<script src='https://unpkg.com/stencil-poc-ng@0.0.1/dist/mycomponent.js'></script>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have done this prior and its working but stencils document 
https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-component-starter says what I have done. Please have a look at Node Modules section

Comment: Stencil documentation does not say in which case this solution is valid. I've detailed my answer to explain why this solution is incompatible with Angular

Comment: Yes I am not complaining about your answer. I am curious about they have Node Modules section and they mentioned it for using it as a node module, so why it is not working is my concern only. BTW Thanks for the answer

Comment: Maybe this solution works with node.js web servers that serves `node_modules` folder, I honestly don't know any possible use case for this kind of implementation

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use stencil component on the Angular project and here they are:

1. Add remote path of your js file, for example:
   https://unpkg.com/{module-name}@{module-version}/dist/{relevant-js-
2. Add your js file to the assets folder, reason is angular finds the assets which are mentioned in the assets array of angular.json or angular.cli.json file.

Thanks @YoukouleleY for suggesting the first solution and for giving a proper reason why I am not able to access the second one